# Pandas - Extract text between two strings

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe whose column has data in the below format:

```
---
- !ruby/hash:Control::Keys
  name: sample1
  value: 101
```

I am trying to extract just the name and values and store them as new column. I tried

```
df['col'].str.extract(r'name:(\w+)value')
```

but it returned `NAN`

Expected values:

```
name,value
sample1,101
```

Comment: is that 4 rows of data or one row of data

Comment: @abhilb, all that data is in one row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
>>> df['names'] = df.col.str.extract(r'(?<=name:)\s+(\w+)')
>>> df['values'] = df.col.str.extract(r'(?<=value:)\s+(\w+)')
>>> df
                                                 col    names values
0  ---\n- !ruby/hash:Control::Keys\n  name: sampl...  sample1    101
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex pattern:

`r'(name: (\w+))|(value: (\w+))`

Keep in mind the spaces.

You will get a list containing ['sample1',101].